# "Postmark::InvalidMessageError: Provide either email TextBody or HtmlBody or both." for a rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, postmark

I was reading through the Postmark documentation, saw the rails gem there ([github link](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-rails)).

I set it up according to the instructions and I ran into this message when I tried sending an email:

```
Provide either email TextBody or HtmlBody or both.
```

I have my email settings in my mailer as such:

```
mail(
  :to       => user.email,
  :subject  => "Thanks for signing up",
  :from     => "me@domain.com",
  "HtmlBody" => "<b>Hello</b>",
  "TextBody" => "Hello"
)
```

Please let me know if you need more information. I'm not sure if this is detailed enough for someone who has seen this error before.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, whether I use Devise or a custom mailer I set up for testing purposes. It seems to be a catch-all error message that doesn't really tell you the cause.

Answer (score 1):

#### Misnaming Email Views

I ran into this same thing and it was due to a misnaming on my part of the views associated with the email.

Example

```
_user_first_logs_in.html.erb  # Was incorrectly using this.

user_first_logs_in.html.erb   # Should be using this.
```

A good way to test for this locally is by using the [mail_view](https://github.com/37signals/mail_view) gem by our trusted [37signals](http://37signals.com/) boys that allows you to preview email in development. Check it out.

That should expose a lot of basic issues.

JP